# possibility to increment a duplicate with foreach loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to increment a duplicate function twice with a "foreach" loop?

For example you have a function which contains an input field. When you call that function you get 2 input fields, but the first one should get "Syllablescounter[0]" and the second one Syllablescounter[1] as a name.

the code overview that's related to it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var id = 0;
 var addOpdracht = $('<a/>', {
'class': 'btn btn-success',
'id': 'addOpdracht'
  }).on('click', function() {
  $('form').append(getExerciseBlock(id));
 $(".exerciseGetWordInput_" + id).focus().select();
 id++;
 exerciseAudioInput++;
 SyllablesID++;
  }).html('<i class="fa fa-plus fa-2x"></i>');

  $('form').append(addOpdracht);
  $('form').append(getExerciseTitle());
  });


function getWordPartInput(id, cValue){
  cValue = cValue || '';
  var wpInput = $('<input/>', {
    'class': 'form-group form-control syllable',
    'type': 'text',
    'value': cValue,
    'placeholder': 'Syllables',
    'id': 'SyllablesGetWordPartInput',
    'name': 'Syllablescounter['+ SyllablesID +']'
  });
  return wpInput;
}
```

The piece of code which I'm looking for to do so:

```
function getWordPartInput(id, cValue){
  cValue = cValue || '';
  var wpInput = $('<input/>', {
    'class': 'form-group form-control syllable',
    'type': 'text',
    'value': cValue,
    'placeholder': 'Syllables',
    'id': 'SyllablesGetWordPartInput',
    'name': 'Syllablescounter['+ SyllablesID +']'
  });
  return wpInput;
}
```

The piece of code above is about the Syllables (the input fields with the blue placeholders). Here you have a fiddle to play with and look for urself, when I click on the green "add" button it indeed increments with "+1", but both standard pop-up syllables end up having the same name counter, when I click on the blue "add" button to add an extra syllable it counts +1, but if u click it again, u see the added syllables have the same name counters as well. I would like to have EACH syllable have a counter for itself. not twice the same number. I was thinking about a "foreach" loop, but i'm not sure if this would help, my apologies if the solution is simple. I'm quite new to javascript/jquery. 
https://jsfiddle.net/DanDy/sa2eowhh/2/

Comment: `SyllablesID` is no even defined in your code? Which are the names you are getting?

Comment: my apologies, the variable was defined all the way up in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the increment from `addOpdracht` button :

```
var addOpdracht = $('<a/>', {
'class': 'btn btn-success',
'id': 'addOpdracht'
  }).on('click', function() {
  $('form').append(getExerciseBlock(id));
 $(".exerciseGetWordInput_" + id).focus().select();
 id++;
 exerciseAudioInput++;
 // SyllablesID++;
  }).html('<i class="fa fa-plus fa-2x"></i>');
```

and increment it in your getWordPartInput function :

```
function getWordPartInput(id, cValue){
  cValue = cValue || '';
  var wpInput = $('<input/>', {
    'class': 'form-group form-control syllable',
    'type': 'text',
    'value': cValue,
    'placeholder': 'Syllables',
    'id': 'SyllablesGetWordPartInput',
    'name': 'Syllablescounter['+ SyllablesID++ +']'
  });
  return wpInput;
}
```

That will automatically use SyllablesID value then increment it by one at each function call.

I've updated your fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/sa2eowhh/3/

Comment: Was just about to post this. No need for a for loop here

Comment: Yep, this did the job. Thank you very much. Yet again, my apologies. I just started javascript and jquery.

Comment: No need to apologize. You did well by providing a fiddle and SO is made to learn and progress ;)